# mailchimp modal integration "There are errors below" with bootstrap hidden-xs and visible-xs

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, mailchimp

I'm having issues with the modal mailchimp pop-up signup form on this [website](http://www.juicecrawl.com). (tip if you want to view more than once, delete your cookies).

I was trying to add another field besides `email` and somehow the form stopped submitting, so I reverted to the original code. However, after revering back to the original code, the popup was showing an error of "There are errors below" after the user submits his/her email. After further chrome console inspection, I noticed that if I delete the form with bootstrap's class `visible-xs` entirely and then remove the class `hidden-xs` from the other form, it seemed to clear things up.

The user can now submit his/her email on mobile or desktop. But I feel like there's something strange happening. Did mailchimp changing something and that broke the code or am I'm just missing something? I have the form with `visible-xs` commented out so you can see when you `view source`.

On top of this I'm trying to add another required `location` field. It's letting the users submit without selecting a location (even though it contains the html `required` attribute. Any ideas how to ensure the form isn't sumbitted without selecting a location field? (This is also current commented out so you can see it in the source code.)

Maybe someone has tips on best practices for all of this? Any idea why I have to delete one form for the whole thing to work? Any ideas to code this modal form better? Ideas to get the location field working? Thanks!

Comment: Just stumbled upon this question - seeing as it's still unanswered (including by yourself), did you manage to solve your issues with the form?

Comment: @Kay no, actually never solved this. Users can still submit without selecting a location and I'm not sure why since I have the required attribute listed.